# No se obtienen valores de checkboxes sino hasta evento click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Tengo una función que ejecuta una consulta y obtengo un data el cual armo **inputs** de tipo **checkboxes** de la siguiente manera:

```
function checkboxPlagues(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: getBaseUri() + 'planthealth/getplagues/'+ id,
      dataType: 'json',
      'error': function(response) {
        redirectPage(response.status);
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var data = response['return'];
        var divs = '';

        for(var i in data){
          divs += '<div class="col-lg-12 no-margin no-padding">'+
                    '<div class="col-lg-12 no-margin no-padding">'+
                      '<input type="checkbox" id="ck_'+ data[i].id +'" name="ck_plague[]" value="'+ data[i].id +'" checked = "checked">'+ data[i].plague +
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>';
        }

        $checkPlague.append(divs);
      }
    });
  }
```

Esta función se ejecuta cuando se cargue la página, hasta ahí bien. Luego lo que hago es capturar los **values** de cada **input** que esten **checked** para enviarlo a una función que me hace una consulta con los valores seleccionados de la siguiente manera:

```
$consult.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var arrPlague = [];

    $("input[name='ck_plague[]']:checked").each(function(){
      arrPlague.push($(this).val());
    });
    resultPlanthealth(arrPlague);
  });
```

`$consult` es el botón que llama la función `resultPlanthealth` y envia un array con los valores de los checkboxes seleccionados de la siguiente manera:

```
function resultPlanthealth(arrPlaguess){

var url = getBaseUri() + 'planthealth/getplaguequadrant/'+ arrPlagues;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    'error': function(response) {
      redirectPage(response.status);
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loading-screen").show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $("#loading-screen").hide();
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var incidence  = response['return'];

      for (var i in incidence) {
          //Aquí armo una tabla pero todo funciona bien
      }
    }
});
  }
```

Para ejecutar el botón `$consult` cuando se cargue la página lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
$consult.click();
```

El problema es que cuando cargo la página no se obtienen los datos de los `checkboxes` y únicamente funciona hasta cuando le de click al botón `$consult`

Pero si creo los checkboxes desde el `HTML` si funciona sin necesidad de dar click al botón `$consult`, pero necesito que sea desde jquery porque debe ser dinámico.

He revisado maneras pero no he podido encontrar como solucionar esto.

Saludos!

Comment: Hace falta la parte donde obtiene lo que corresponde a `$consult`; puede ser te falte iniciarlizar y/o asignar a dicha variable "algo" *(lo que le corresponda)*

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas la inicializo desde esta manera `var $consult      = $("#consult");` solo es un botón

Comment: Asumiendo que `$consult` ya existe como corresponde coloca  `$consult.click();` después de `$checkPlague.append(divs);` (que está dentro de `checkboxPlagues`)

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas muchas gracias si me funcionó, si sospechaba que era la forma de colocar el llamado del botón

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas sugiero que escribas una respuesta con la solución, para que este caso quede resuelto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos**

Bastará con que el llamado `$consult.click();` sea realizado desde función `checkboxPlagues` justo después de la línea `$checkPlague.append(divs);`; es decir:

```
function checkboxPlagues(id){
    $.ajax({
      url: getBaseUri() + 'planthealth/getplagues/'+ id,
      dataType: 'json',
      'error': function(response) {
        redirectPage(response.status);
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var data = response['return'];
        var divs = '';

        for(var i in data){
          divs += '<div class="col-lg-12 no-margin no-padding">'+
                    '<div class="col-lg-12 no-margin no-padding">'+
                      '<input type="checkbox" id="ck_'+ data[i].id +'" name="ck_plague[]" value="'+ data[i].id +'" checked = "checked">'+ data[i].plague +
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>';
        }

        $checkPlague.append(divs);
        $consult.click(); /* Aquí se invoca */
      }
    });
  }
```

> En atención para que quede resuelto